# How to fix "E libOpenSLES: Too many objects" in SoundEffect qml

Tags: android, qt, qml

I'm coding a small android soundboard app and I'm using the SoundEffect component inside a `ListDelegate`. But after a certain number of buttons are pressed (sound.play() is called) it stops playing sounds and I get this error in the application output:

> E libOpenSLES: Too many objects W libOpenSLES: Leaving
>
> Engine::CreateAudioPlayer (SL_RESULT_MEMORY_FAILURE)
>
> W sound : Unable to create AudioPlayer

Inside A ListDelegate:

```
Rectangle{

   ...

  Button{
    id: delegateButton
    anchors.fill: parent
    Material.elevation: 0
    onPressed: sound.play();
  }

  SoundEffect{
    id: sound
    source: soundsource
  }
}
```

Comment: `SoundEffect` inside delegate??? For what??

Comment: I am using soundEffect inside the delegate so i could specify a different audiosource for each button using a listmodel

Comment: Ehmm ... Do you play all these soundd simultaneously? If not - create one instance and so set source from the delegate. `SoundEffect` should be kinda singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by moving the sound effect component out of the delegate and dynamically change the audio source when the button is clicked like so:

Inside the delegate:

```
Rectangle{
 signal tapped();
   ...

  Button{
    id: delegateButton
    anchors.fill: parent
    Material.elevation: 0
    onPressed: tapped()
  }
}
```

Inside my Main Page:

```
SoundEffect{
  id: sound
}

 ...

ListView{
  delegate:{
    ...

    onTapped: {sound.source = audiosource; sound.play()}
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Additionally I would move `play()` to `onStatusChanged()` since setting `source` does not guarantee that the item will be immediately ready to play.